# VBA to paste active cell data into columns

Tags: vba

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

I'm new to VBA. I'm trying to do crew scheduling, so one employee will do 28 days work and 28 days off and goes on for 10 employees.

This code works only from D4 and goes on. This is good but I need is the code to work on any empty cell I click. Say I select on G4 or H4 etc, it should start the copying from there.

```vb
    Sub CopyToColumn2()
            Dim lLastCol As Long
            lLastCol = WorksheetFunction.Max(4, Cells(1, Columns.Count)_
                .End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Column)
            Cells(1, lLastCol).Resize(1, 10).Value = Application.Transpose(Array(Range("B5")))
        End Sub
```

Test Sheet:

[image]

Comment: Can you re-write your code to be more readable

Comment: Should `B5` change based on which cell is selected when you run the code?

Comment: You should investigate theWorksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) event

Comment: Sub CopyToColumn2()
Dim lLastCol As Long
lLastCol = WorksheetFunction.Max(4, Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Column)
Cells(1, lLastCol).Resize(1, 25).Value = Application.Transpose(Array(Range("B5")))
End Sub

Comment: @norie No the B5 should remain the same. If I click on any empty cell. It should start copying from there instead of D4

Comment: @DougCoats Can you please let me know how to do that. I'm very new to the VBA. :-(

Comment: It will be better you can show image of your sample data and the expected result, I think quite easy to solve also.

Comment: @KinSiang screenshot attached

Comment: If you click on `G4`, you want to copy data from `G4:G20` or also `B4:B20`, since there is no data on `G4` also?

Comment: @KinSiang if I click on any empty cell on any row, it should copy from there on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may perform a testing for using the following code modification, although it will only copy to `D1` with resize method:

```
Sub CopyToColumn2()
Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long, i As Long

lastrow = ActiveCell.Row
lastcol = ActiveCell.Column

For i = 0 To 3
    Range(Cells(lastrow + i, lastcol), Cells(lastrow + i, lastcol + 9)).Value = Range("B6")
Next
End Sub
```

**My sample data:**

[image]

Comment: Where do you select? Not sure why you are  getting the error, see my sample data above

Comment: Hi Kin, It worked but it was not a continuous loop. It stops after copying 4 columns. What I want is to copy the active cell(say B5) and paste the data in columns(wherever I selected, Say J4, it should start from J4,K4, and so on. If I select from D5, it should start from D5,E5 and so on)

Comment: I see, when you paste the value, do you need to transpose the data, else it will keep overwrite the first row? Maybe you should share more about your data with image.

Comment: I uploaded the link to the sheet. It needs to transpose the data. Please have a look

Comment: I cannot access the link, maybe explain with image is sufficient?

Comment: Hi Kin, Upload. Please check. If i click on any empty cell the "WT" must be pasted from that empty cell to so on

Comment: See my edited answer, this will be my last try, hope you find it useful.

Comment: Hi Kin, You are the champ. This is what I exactly need. Thank You

Comment: Welcome, accept the answer if helping you :)